# How can you implement a custom comparator for 'in' using python

Tags: python

If i had a class like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.z = z
```

In a list like this:

```
list = [foo(1, 2, 3), foo(4, 5, 6), foo(7, 8, 9)]
```

How could i create a custom test for 'in' such that it checks only x and z values such that this:

```
new_foo = foo(1,8,3)
if new_foo in list:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Would print True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `in` on lists tests using equality, so you need to define an `__eq__` method: see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).  You will also need to define a `__hash__` method to ensure that your objects compare equal in a consistent manner if they have mutable state.  For instance:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.z = z

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x, self.z) == (other.x, other.z)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.z))
```

You should think carefully about whether you really want to do this, though.  It defines a notion of equality which will apply in all situations where equality is tested.  So if you do what you ask for in your post, then `foo(1,2,3) == foo(1,8,3)` will be true in general, not just when using `in`.

Comment: Like the OP - your `__init__` isn't using `self` and your example does for `__eq__` and `__hash__` - also I think the OP is asking for `__contains__`

Comment: `__contains__` defines the containment check on the *container*.  You use it to define containment check on a custom container type.  But the OP wants to check for a custom object contained in an ordinary list.  `__contains__` is no good for that.

Comment: Thanks.  I just copied the OP's code without even noticing that it had errors.